# How to add previous and next buttons to a list view

Tags: android-studio, for-loop, listview, adapter

I currently have a listview which holds unlimited amounts of input but I only want it to hold 5 rows at a time and then the user can select the next button which will move the listview to the next 5 rows and then can select the previous to view the 5 previous. I am currently uncertain on how to do this so any guidance would be very useful. I thought maybe i could use a for loop with a starting point of position and an endpoint of position  + 10 (i.e. the loop would start with for (int i = position; i < position+10; i++)). and then at each iteration, add the array entry at that position. Would this work somewhere in my code? Please any help would make me so so so grateful!!!!!

InventoryStatus Class:
public class InventoryStatus extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDB;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_status);


    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewStock);
    Button btNext = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    Button btPrevious = findViewById(R.id.buttonPrevious);

    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getAllData();

    if(data.getCount() == 0 ){
        Toast.makeText(InventoryStatus.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        while (data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add("Name: " + data.getString(0) + " Quantity: " + data.getString(1) + " Type: " + data.getString(2));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
    btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    btPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

Activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".InventoryStatus">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewStock"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="359dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewInventoryStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/inventory_status"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.549"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.967" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/previous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.967" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Listview is deprecated and I don't encourage you to use it

Comment: Use recyclerview instead. Any way in both cases you can define arraylist to hold the whole data then update the adapter with the current 5 items you want to show. Or instead of the arraylist you can directly select  5 items each time from local DB and use OFFSET and LIMIT in your query to move next and previous

Comment: @RamyMalak so having a listview with previous and next buttons wouldnt be able to work?

Comment: It will work but it is not recommended

Comment: @RamyMalak Yeah its more just for testing it out to see if I could get it to work with a list view somehow... Do you know how I could go about doing so?

Comment: I've already explained previously how you can do this in both cases either listview or recyclerview. apply the same logic above